# Mono - SharePoint CSOM licensing

Tags: csom, licensing, linux

I am wanting to use this nuget package on Mono: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM

Is it legal to use CSOM in a Linux mono program?

There is the following license attached: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=280198

saying

> Distribution Restrictions. You may not
>   distribute Distributable Code to run on a platform other than the Windows platform;

Does that mean I can have users of my code download the DLLs separately (I will not send my program with CSOM DLLs bundled in, I will make them download them separately directly from Microsoft)?

Or does that mean that I cannot use CSOM on Linux/mac *at all*?

Comment: I would strongly suggest creating an issue at https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP. This will get you in touch with the PG who may be able to better answer your question.

Comment: Done. I've been sending twitters, send contacts over to the list attached to the nuget libraries, and more. so far radio silence. 

I also created a ticket on the Docs website as well, someone requested i do that prior.

hopefully this helps. https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP/issues/1805

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the conclusion is that you may not run it on Linux at all, but I'm not a lawyer.

Linux support is being worked on: https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329220-sharepoint-dev-platform/suggestions/16585795-support-net-core-with-csom

If you are really looking for a solution, than that might be worth waiting for.

The other option you have is to use the rest endpoints, although these might not support everything you want.

Comment: So my mono code was already working on Linux which means it was working on .NET core already. I built it specifically to avoid CSOM features that didn't work yet on .NET core. So the only thing left in my way is that old restrictive license on CSOM which prohibits cross platform. That is clearly a left over boilerplate license that needs replaced with something that allows cross platform.

Comment: And my assumption is they won't change it as they are working on a .net core version.

Comment: man i really hope they get it working soon. the REST api sucks compared to using CSOM